# Get Minimum Value for Each Person

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get the first request date by each employee. To get the first one I am trying to use the `MIN` because it will give me the first date.

My problem is that I am getting a "not a single-group function" error on my `SELECT` statement. I am certain that it has to do with the `MIN` but I have been messing around with it and cannot seem to figure it out.

```
SELECT empid, firstname, lastname, MIN(request_date) AS first_request_date
FROM employee e
JOIN requests r ON e.empid = r.requester_id
ORDER BY first_request_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use an aggregate function such as `MIN()`, you need a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT empid, firstname, lastname, MIN(r.request_date) AS first_request_date
FROM employee e
JOIN requests r ON e.empid = r.requester_id
GROUP BY e.empid, e.firstname, e.lastname
ORDER BY first_request_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Group by for aggregate function.

```sql
SELECT empid,
       firstname,
       lastname,
       Min(request_date) AS first_request_date
FROM   employee e
       JOIN requests r
         ON e.empid = r.requester_id
GROUP  BY empid,
          firstname,
          lastname
ORDER  BY first_request_date
```

Comment: Your code will produce the same Oracle error. This is NOT MySQL.